# Regex for given DFA

Tags: regex

I have constructed following DFA for my problem:
[image]

I have tried following regex

```
(T+X?T+)+

  where
    T = [a-z0-9]
    X = [-.]
```

But is not working.

Comment: The arrow on the top left leads out of nowhere into state 0. Arrows can be only between states. You need an initial state to be identified. If 0 is the initial state, then it means that your machine recognizes empty strings, because it's also an acceptance state. If 0 is the initial state, the arrow leading into it from nowhere is superfluous.

Comment: If your goal is to produce a regex which is then applied to input, then constructing a DFA is a poor way to start. If graphing helps you, graph out an NFA, not a DFA.  Going from DFA to regex is a bit like converting ground beef to a cow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your notation, let see how the DFA works.

It accepts a symbol from `T` first and enters state `0`. This is also the final state, that's why everything we put after `T` should be quantified with `?` (0 or 1 times) or `*` (0 or many times).

In state `0` it accepts a symbol from `T` and remains in state `0` or a symbol from `X` followed by a symbol from `T` to go back to state `0`. The subexpression is `T|XT` and it can happen zero or more times.

The complete `regex` is `T(T|XT)*`. Using the usual notation, the regular expression you need is:

```
[0-9a-z]([0-9a-z]|[-.][0-9a-z])*
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you are trying to match full string.

```
^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|([.-][a-z0-9]))*)$
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/zT7zK1/3)

Comment: `-` doesn't need to be escaped in any context. The OP already provided a way to put `-` and `.` in the regexp without the need to quote them (`[-.]`).